# React - Multi HTML Pages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm building an application using React. My problem is that I have multiple HTML pages and I want to open one of them when I click on a button. But when that HTML opens up, React does not render that page although. What should I do to resolve that?

I've already seen React Router but it seems like to be for the same HTML page. I want to open a different HTML page not to render on the same page at different times.

I tried to do this in the HTML I open when I click the button

`<script src="../src/app.js"></script>`

but it does nothing.

tl;dr - A button opens a new HTML page. How to make React render that page?

Comment: React is Single Page Application framework. You can't render html page. You need to transform it into jsx.

Comment: ّIf that's the app you have, I don't think react will help you in this, react is for single page application, if its simple pages convert HTML pages to components and use react router to render the URLs.

Comment: thx, that was a good response

Comment: You can try also next.js for ssr

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, then you need to reformulate the question. You might need to add iframes of external static html files.

This is something that was answered here correctly, so I won't duplicate.

[Render HTML inside a React app using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603641/render-html-inside-a-react-app-using-iframe)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thx for the answer but I think the comments in my post were the answer I needed, thx anyway